# Put icon before sub category

Tags: magento-1.9, code, submenu

I'd like to put font awsome icon before al my level2 menu

Exemple :

1. Menu 1 (on mouse)

   - Submenu 1

     - (icon) Submenu 2
     - (icon) Submenu 3
     - (icon) Submenu 4

But I can't figure out where the file is, I've found topmenu, headder.phtml but I'm not good enough to do this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

The menu is rendered in the `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu_Renderer` so you'll need to overwrite it's `drawItem` method to add HTML.

A better solution is using CSS, specially the `:before` selector

```
.nav-container .nav-horizontal li.level1:before {
    content: url('../images/icon.png');
}
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Ok thanks i'll try this, but it will work for code of font awesome like : <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i> or i must put an image ?
Where can i find the file to edit the thing you said ?

Comment: ah in that case you might need to insert a character code as `content`. I'm no frontender so I don't know 100% how but I know it's possible with awesome font